# Cannot make static method \Loader::load() non static in class Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader

Tags: laravel, authentication

Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Cannot make static method Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader::load() non static in class Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader

I cant't access anymore to the login / register page on browser. comes out this error and on the console comes out error internal 500 .
This is the file that the error is pointer .

```
 <?php

namespace Illuminate\Translation;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Loader;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use RuntimeException;

class FileLoader implements Loader
{
    /**
     * The filesystem instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem
     */
    protected $files;

    /**
     * The default path for the loader.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * All of the registered paths to JSON translation files.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $jsonPaths = [];

    /**
     * All of the namespace hints.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hints = [];

    /**
     * Create a new file loader instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem  $files
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    /**
     * Load the messages for the given locale.
     *
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string|null  $namespace
     * @return array
     */
    public static function load($locale, $group, $namespace = null)
    {
        if ($group === '*' && $namespace === '*') {
            return $this->loadJsonPaths($locale);
        }

        if (is_null($namespace) || $namespace === '*') {
            return $this->loadPath($this->path, $locale, $group);
        }

        return $this->loadNamespaced($locale, $group, $namespace);
    }

    /**
     * Load a namespaced translation group.
     *
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @return array
     */
    protected function loadNamespaced($locale, $group, $namespace)
    {
        if (isset($this->hints[$namespace])) {
            $lines = $this->loadPath($this->hints[$namespace], $locale, $group);

            return $this->loadNamespaceOverrides($lines, $locale, $group, $namespace);
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Load a local namespaced translation group for overrides.
     *
     * @param  array  $lines
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $group
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @return array
     */
    protected function loadNamespaceOverrides(array $lines, $locale, $group, $namespace)
    {
        $file = "{$this->path}/vendor/{$namespace}/{$locale}/{$group}.php";

        if ($this->files->exists($file)) {
            return array_replace_recursive($lines, $this->files->getRequire($file));
        }

        return $lines;
    }

    /**
     * Load a locale from a given path.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @param  string  $group
     * @return array
     */
    protected function loadPath($path, $locale, $group)
    {
        if ($this->files->exists($full = "{$path}/{$locale}/{$group}.php")) {
            return $this->files->getRequire($full);
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Load a locale from the given JSON file path.
     *
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    protected function loadJsonPaths($locale)
    {
        return collect(array_merge($this->jsonPaths, [$this->path]))
            ->reduce(function ($output, $path) use ($locale) {
                if ($this->files->exists($full = "{$path}/{$locale}.json")) {
                    $decoded = json_decode($this->files->get($full), true);

                    if (is_null($decoded) || json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Translation file [{$full}] contains an invalid JSON structure.");
                    }

                    $output = array_merge($output, $decoded);
                }

                return $output;
            }, []);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new namespace to the loader.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string  $hint
     * @return void
     */
    public function addNamespace($namespace, $hint)
    {
        $this->hints[$namespace] = $hint;
    }

    /**
     * Get an array of all the registered namespaces.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function namespaces()
    {
        return $this->hints;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new JSON path to the loader.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return void
     */
    public function addJsonPath($path)
    {
        $this->jsonPaths[] = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get an array of all the registered paths to JSON translation files.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonPaths()
    {
        return $this->jsonPaths;
    }
}
```

Waiting for some suggestions thank you !!!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what changed from when it was working until now? did you update something?  I can't find a time when that method was ever `static` in the history of that file

Comment: No, but the original function was ``` public function load() {...}  ``` and I tryed to resolve the problem making it ``` public static load() {...} ``` and it gives the a new error to $this inside the function. And it's very weir because I didn't find nothing similar on google

Comment: don't edit files in `vendor` and you can't make that function `static`

Comment: I haven't update nothing else, so I have no idea were is the error, I only have the load() function error and inside the console it gives me only the internal error 500

Comment: the interface has never declared that method as static and the FileLoader class has never defined that method as static ... so that error doesn't make much sense ... make sure that "contract" (interface), `Loader`, it is talking about doesn't have that method defined as `static`